# Catch the 400 Bad request before stopping the script

Tags: python, web, urllib

I downloaded files like this and it sometimes returns 400 request.

```
f = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,"filename")
```

So I would like to check if it returns 400 error ,skip and continue to the next procedure.

However if it returns 400 , the program stops with this error.

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

How can I don't let `400 error` stop the program?

Comment: Use Try/Except?

Comment: try catch can catch 400 with all httperror and then use if else

Comment: I use Try / Except thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try catch blocks. Assuming that `urllib` is already imported

```
try: 
    f = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,"filename")
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print("Error: ", e)
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I resolved the problem with try except function.